# How to embed multiple python interpreters in a c++ program with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Using pybind11, I'd like to embed multiple interpreters: I want to launch multiple threads, and in each thread, start an interpreter, eval_file, and then stop the interpreter and shut down the thread.

Basically, this is a thread function:

```
pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{};
pybind11::eval_file(python_filename);
```

Compilation is fine, but at runtime I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  The interpreter is already running
```

I guess this is a no-no. But why? How would it even know?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#sub-interpreter-support